# Crashlytics doesn't find my fabric.properties

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am trying to set up Crashlytics in my Application but I get the message **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element**  but I don't want to put my key in androidManifest so I have to create fabric.properties, right? There is my set up until now.

Fabric.properties in `/app/fabric.properties`

```
apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Initialize on `OnCreate()` of Application class.

```
private void setupCrashlytics(){
        CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());

    }
```

Set up dependecy in `gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'witness'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.douglas"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 31
        versionName "0.4.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        beta {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir file('jniLibs')
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
        compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
        compile 'org.thoughtcrime.ssl.pinning:AndroidPinning:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'
        compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
        compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can link to your full build.gradle? Also, can you remove your API key so that it's not public?

Comment: @Alexizamerican here is it, man!

Comment: Thanks! What buildType are you running when you hit that error?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: same here. Any solutions for this?

Comment: I think their docs are just plain wrong.. I tried so many things and eventually just caved and put it into the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with **fabric gradle plugin 1.25.4** which seems to be fixed after updating the fabric gradle version to 1.31.0

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
```

Thanks to this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206074/6671572