# Fabric crashlytics new implementation not working | fabric.properties

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

The implementation to put the `apiSecret` and `apiKey` in the `fabric.properties` file isn’t working anymore.

## Fabric properties file: app/fabric.properties

```
apiSecret=xx68f6074dxxxxxc11dxxx97c172e8ebf0
apiKey=xxxe76c4xxxx97e8cxxxx0135e9d46f5a2xxx
```

Add to `.gitignore` (for open source projects)

Remove the entry at the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxx6c41xxx6ec601xxxd4xxxa2" />
```

Official documentation: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#android-projects

Does anymore know what have changed or why this isn’t working anymore?

Comment: If you are new user to fabric then it is better to use Firebase. For existing user it is recommended to migrate firebase. see Official documents https://get.fabric.io/roadmap?utm_campaign=discover&utm_medium=natural#transition-plan  @Kushaal Singla

Comment: @Mohsinkazi is it mandatory

Comment: if you are existing user then till March 31, 2020  you can use it. If you are new user then better to use firebase.it is mandatory after March 31, 2020 @Kushaal Singla

Comment: I have the same issue (and reported it a week ago, no answer, yet) and for me it is related to building an Android App Bundle instead of an APK. Looking at crashlytics.log I suspect this is because Fabric only modifies the manifest file used to build an APK (e.g. in app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release), but not the one used to build an AAB (e.g. in app/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/processReleaseManifest/bundle-manifest).

Comment: @KushaalSingla Could you add the version of Android Gradle plugin you're using?

Comment: @KevinKokomani         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

Comment: @KevinKokomani         
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.30.0'

Comment: @KushaalSingla Could you try updating as in the answer by uwe? That should fix this for you.

Comment: @KevinKokomani i didn't get you..uwe???

Comment: @KushaalSingla The answer provided by the user "uwe" below to upgrade to version 1.31.0 of the Fabric Gradle plugin should fix your issue. If you haven't upgraded already, I recommend trying that out.

Comment: @KevinKokomani already done but still not working.

Comment: @KushaalSingla Hm, interesting - would you mind reaching out to support@fabric.io with this information? Support can take a closer look at your issue if the upgraded plugin isn't helping you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to have been fixed (at least for me) with **version 1.31.0 (July 24, 2019) of the Fabric Gradle plugin**:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
```

Now when building an App Bundle the AndroidManifest.xml file includes the io.fabric.ApiKey meta-data element.

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#july-24-2019